# Create Socket.IO server with express.js in a module and access it from other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to have a module to which I pass an [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) app that creates a server with Socket.IO. In the `require` calls after, I want to return the `io` object.

Here's what I have:

`ioserver.js`

```
var http = require("http");

module.exports = function (expressApp) {
    var server = http.createServer(expressApp);
    var io = require("socket.io")(server);
    return io;
};
```

`sample-request.js`

```
var io = require("./ioserver");
console.log("sample request io", io);
```

`index.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var io = require("./modules/ioserver")(app);
console.log("index io", io);

var sampleRequest = require("./modules/sample-request");
```

### Problem

In `index.js`, the log returns the `io` object, as expected:

```
index io Server {
  nsps:
   { '/':
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Circular],
        sockets: {},
        ...
```

In the samples module, though, the log looks like:

```
sample request io function (expressApp) {
    var server = http.createServer(expressApp);
    var io = require("socket.io")(server);
    return io;
}
```

### Question

Why is this happening? I want is to have access to the `io` object created in `index.js` from `sample-request.js`. I noticed that if I pass an argument to the `require` in the sample module, a new server is created and the log there is simply the new server.

Could the problem be because in one place, I `require` the module with the path `./modules/ioserver` and in the other - with `./ioserver`? Based on [what I've read](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it. I don't know if it's the *best* way, but it works. If anyone has a better solution, please share it.

`ioserver.js`

```
var http = require("http");
var io = null;

module.exports = function (expressApp) {
    if (io === null && expressApp) {
        var server = http.createServer(expressApp);
        io = require("socket.io")(server);
    }

    return io;
};
```

`sample-request.js`

```
var io = require("./ioserver")();
```

`index.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var io = require("./modules/ioserver")(app);
var sampleRequest = require("./modules/sample-request");
```

---

Note that in `sample-request.js`, I *invoke* the returned object from `require()`:

```
var io = require("./ioserver")();
------------------------------^^
```

If I don't, I get the same value as the one I got in my question.